# Update or Insert value if a field is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I know this is a very simple question but I just wanted to be sure.
I have a Null value in a field, and I want to change that Null value. To change the Null Value Do I use Insert or update?

```
For Example:
Insert Into dataTable (Column 1)
Values (1)
WHERE 'Column 1' = NULL
```

OR

```
UPDATE dataTable 
SET 'Column 1' = 1
WHERE 'Column 1' = NULL
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You use [`UPDATE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) for updates and [`INSERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) for inserts(new records). But your update is incorrect since you cannot compare `NULL` values with `=` or `<>`. Therefore you have to use [`IS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx):

```
UPDATE dataTable 
SET [Column 1] = 1
WHERE [Column 1] IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are existing rows, you want update.  But the big thing is you want to use "is NULL" instead of = NULL.

```
UPDATE dataTable 
SET 'Column 1' = 1
WHERE 'Column 1' IS NULL
```